# How to install a Macromedia Flash Player "pdf reader" on a Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, flash, pdf, macromedia

I am trying to install a Macromedia Flash Player "pdf reader" on my wordpress website just like this person has done on his: http://www.drkamikaze.com/maths-library/mm_2013_pr_1_que_final.html

Anyone know how if there is a plugin that will do this? Any simpler way through inserting of a code? I actually am not even sure of what language the code would be in. If anyone could give me more insight, that would be great.

Thanks!

EDIT: Apparently, thanks to the comment from C. Parcell, I now know that it is possible to convert a PDF to a SWF file. However, I still need to be able to install the Macromedia Flash Player plugin on my website that essentially "looks like" a pdf reader but I guess is not. Does anyone know how this is done? Basically, I just want a pdf "reader" that will only allow people to view and NOT download/save or highlight/copy the text.

Thanks again, C. Parcell for your comment.

Comment: Did you try? : [FlexPaper PDF Reader](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/wordpress.jsp) or maybe [Wordpress PDF plugin](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=cr&ei=nqYkUqj1Osi20QXAhoHoDQ#q=free+pdf+reader+wordpress)

Comment: For a little more clarity, this is NOT a PDF reader. It is a converter and it makes a completely separate file. There is a converter that will make a SWF based on a PDF. Baked into that SWF file will be the UI tools to allow a user to scroll, zoom, page turn, etc.

Comment: VC.One: I checked FlexPaper PDF reader out and it seems to meet my needs, but it is $149! What is the other plugin that you posted? It seems that it just takes me to google search. Thanks so much!